# Title text wide as same as the block in CSS

Tags: css, title

I have this block:

[image]

For example: I add the text: Last News in the world.

I would like to have the width of the block as wide as the text, but the corners should still remain as a curve.

CSS:

```
.cat-box-title h2 {
    background: transparent url(.../images/testtitle.png) repeat-y;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color:#5E5E5E;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: BebasNeueRegular, arial, Georgia, serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cat-box-title">
    title
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using image you must use css3 technique, However if you want to stick with image. There is a method called `sliding door technique` where you required 2 images. you can found a lots of article if you use that term.

A related link is here .http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/how-to-create-sliding-doors-with-css.html#fbid=q4O2prbtZUy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
.cat-box-title {
             background-color: #4679bd; 
             color:#5E5E5E;
             float:left;
             border-radius:5px;
             margin-right:10px;
             font-size: 22px;
             padding: 5px;
             font-family: BebasNeueRegular,arial,Georgia, serif;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, what do I need to change in the CSS to set the block on maximum width?

Comment: add the property width: 100%; in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will be more easy if you use the `border-radius` instead of background image.

```
.round-btn
{
  background:#4679bd;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding : 10px;
  border:none;
}
```

of-course you need to check the browser compatibility whether your browser supports this property or not. If not then you need to use some hack.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v2z8D/1/)

and if you goes with background-image solution then you need to use two images; one for left side border-radius and another one for right side and use the `background-color` for rest of the button.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean, I added some CSS and HTML in my question, can you help me with that information?